# MVC CheckBoxList last parameter wants bool instead of collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to hook up a form to a single model or viewmodel, which has a list of checkboxes.  These checkboxes correspond to a list of permissions that the user has in the DB.  Getting those arent the issue, its bundling them along with user information into a single model that I can use on the form AND be availble when posting back to a controller method.

Im trying to use the MVC CheckBoxList helper and I'm tripping over a few things.
MVC CheckBoxList helper:
[MvcCheckBoxList](https://github.com/mikhail-tsennykh/MvcCheckBoxList)

The example code uses this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(x => x.PostedCities.CityIDs,  // checkbox list name, 'PostedCities.CityIDs' in this case
                      x => x.AvailableCities,       // List<City>()
                      x => x.Id,                    // City.Id
                      x => x.Name,                  // City.Name
                      x => x.SelectedCities)        // List<City>() - should contain only cities to be selected
```

However, when I start to provide the last parameter (SelectedCities in the above case), it wants a bool, not a collection.

My ViewModel:

```
public class UserDetailsModel
{
    public string CheckBoxListName { get; set; }
    public UserInfo UserDetails { get; set; }        
    public IList<PermissionCheckBoxInfo> AvailablePermissions { get; set; }
    public IList<PermissionCheckBoxInfo> SelectedPermissions { get; set; }
    public PostedPermissions PostedPermissions { get; set; }
}


public class PostedPermissions
{
    public string[] PermissionIDs { get; set; }
}
```

Helper class:

```
public class PermissionCheckBoxInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }           // Integer value of a checkbox        
    public object Tags { get; set; }      // Object of html tags to be applied to checkbox, e.g.: 'new { tagName = "tagValue" }'
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }  // Boolean value to select a checkbox on the list
}
```

In my view:

```
    @Html.CheckBoxListFor(model=>model.PostedPermissions.PermissionIDs,
                          model=>model.AvailablePermissions,
                          x=>x.Id,
                          x=>x.Name,
                          a => ???)
```

Couple of questions:
The first parameter is the name of the checkbox?  In the example its an array?  
Why not just use a string in the ViewModel?
Also, I need to send back the current user id associated with these slections to the controller action, how can I include that?

Comment: Show your `PermissionCheckBoxInfo` class - does it have properties `Id` and `Name` and a `bool` property to indicate if the checkbox is selected or not?

Comment: You can use `@Html.CheckBoxListFor(x => x.PostedPermissions.PermissionIDs, x => x.AvailablePermissions, x = >x.Id, x => x.Name, a => x.IsSelected)`. Its not clear what the purpose of your `CheckBoxListName` property is and I do not understand what you asking in the first 2 questions.

Comment: And if your controller POST method accepts `PostedPermissions`, then you need to add a property for the user to that class. but what would be the point ao generating an input for the current user and posting it back when your controller already knows that information?

Comment: 1st question - why set the checkbox name to that of an array?  Wait a min, I think I just figured it out - a list of checkboxes or radio buttons typically use the same name.  2nd question - I need more than just the list of selected checkboxes in the action method, because i will need to know what user to set the permissions for.  What would be a good way to include that, assuming I have it in the UserDetails property?
Also, so what are they doing in the "BaseExample" on the docs page (see link above) where they use x => x.SelectedCities as the last parameter?

Comment: But you know the user. When you submit your form, just get the ID of the current user. There is no reason to include it in the view

Comment: Ok, good point, now I recall I already seen the UseDetails was populated when I was debugging earlier.  That part is ok.  Still not sure though about the "BaseExample" above

Comment: Also, I just need have my controller method take a view model, instead of the PostedPermissions.   Please set your previous comment as the answer.  Thanks for the help!